# Web App: How is administrator access usually done

Tags: authentication, web-applications, usergroups

Currently I'm building a web app. So far I only have regular users. However, due to some requirements I need to have special admin accounts for the app administrators. I'm wondering now how these are usually implemented. The requirement is, that they use the same login mask as regular users and behave the same except for the additional capabilities. To differentiate I could put an admin flag into the users' profile or put the admins into a separate table in my DB. Maybe the the second option scales better for potential additional user groups. Also, how could these admins be signed up? I don't want to use predefined usernames I check against in the login handler. I know the question is rather general. I'm just looking for some directions.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't give information about the platform(s) you are using, I can only give theoretical answer.  While a simple "isadmin checkbox" will do the job for only separating normal users and admins, but if you will need another user type such as "power users" etc. you will keep adding new columns to your table, which is not ideal. Basically you can use a "Role Based" or a "Permission" based approach. In Role based, as the name implies, you assign each user a role and give access to specific resources depending on the role. In the "Permissions" approach you define for each user the permissions they have (resources to access, actions they can perform). Also you could combine these two approaches, where you assign each user his role and define permissions for each role.

Comment: Thank you, I actually was looking for theoretical answers. The role based approach seems to suit my needs best.